# Vue.js: v-for iteration with two variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to write a **v-for** iteration with two variables?

I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="apple in apples" v-for="banana in bananas">
    {{ apple .message }}
    {{ banana .message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: before iterating,, push the array elements into single array and then iterate. its simple and easy

Comment: What happens if the arrays are of different length?

Comment: If you use lodash, you can look at `_.zip`

Answer (score 3):

I'd create a computed property that combines both arrays into an array of objects.

This way, you can also accommodate differing lengths. For example

```
computed: {
  fruit() {
    const fruit = []
    for (let i = 0, len = Math.max(this.apples.length, this.bananas.length); i < len; i++) {
      fruit.push({
        appleMessage: this.apples[i] && this.apples[i].message || 'no apple message',
        bananaMessage: this.bananas[i] && this.bananas[i].message || 'no banana message'
      })
    }
    return fruit
  }
}
```

then you can iterate with

```
<li v-for="f in fruit">
  {{ f.appleMessage }}
  {{ f.bananaMessage }}
</li>
```

Demo ~ http://jsfiddle.net/wzmL1y6q/

Answer (score 0):

What about something like that ?

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="(apple, index) in apples">
    {{ apple.message }}
    {{ banana[index].message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

But you have to be sure that the lists have the same length.

Comment: Instead of downvoting, explain why my answer is bad, it's a way more helpful :)

Comment: I upvoted. As far as simple solutions that will _probably_ work go, this is a good fit. I suppose you might garner some downvotes for fragility (eg arrays are different lengths).

Comment: alternatively, you could use `v-for="(fruit, index) in apples.concat(banana)"`

Comment: @Phil given the structure and context of the question, it would work just fine.

Comment: @Derek no, OP wants to show the entries from `apples` and `bananas` at the same index. Using `concat` would just create a longer array, eg `[apple1, apple2, banana1]`